# Double integral and change of variable

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, multiple-integral, change-of-variable

$$
\iint_D \left(x^2-y^2\right)\ dxdy
$$
over $D$ which is bounded by region enclosed by the four curves $y = x, y = x + 1, xy = 1$ and $xy = 2$ in the first quadrant.

What will be a suitable change of variable for this question?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognize and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: Often a good thing is to define $u,v$ in terms of $x,y$ in such a way that the boundaries of the region become $u=\hbox{constant}$ and $v=\hbox{constant}$.  Haven't tried so I don't know whether it works in this case.

Comment: Why change variables?

Comment: Yes, I have tried that but neither does u=x-y and v=x+y work nor does u=xy and v=x^2-y^2. Do you have any better definition?

Answer (score 4):

Notice that
$$D=\{(x,y)\in \mathbb{R}^{2}: y=x, y=x+1, xy=1, xy=2\}$$
With the change of variables $$u=x-y\quad \text{and}\quad v=xy$$
We can re-write the region $D$ as
$$D^{*}=\{(u,v)\in \mathbb{R}^{2}: -1\leqslant u \leqslant 0, \quad 1\leqslant v\leqslant 2\}=[-1,0]\times[1,2]$$
Hence by the change of variables theorem for double integration, we have
$$\iint_{D}f(x,y)\, {\rm d}A=\iint_{D^{*}}f(x(u,v),y(u,v))\left|\frac{\partial(x,y)}{\partial(u,v)}\right|\, {\rm d}A^{*}$$
where $f(x,y)=x^{2}-y^{2}$.

Well,

- We get $\displaystyle \left|\frac{\partial(u,v)}{\partial(x,y)}\right|=x+y>0$ over first quadrant. Hence since $\displaystyle \left|\frac{\partial(x,y)}{\partial(u,v)}\frac{\partial(u,v)}{\partial(x,y)}\right|=1$ we get $\displaystyle \left|\frac{\partial(x,y)}{\partial(u,v)}\right|=\frac{1}{x+y}$.
- Also we have $f(x,y)=x^{2}-y^{2}=(x-y)(x+y)$.

Therefore,

\begin{align*}
\iint_{D}(x^{2}-y^{2})\, {\rm d}A&=\iint_{D^{*}}(x+y)(x-y)\frac{1}{x+y}\, {\rm d}A^{*},\\ &=\int_{1}^{2}\int_{-1}^{0}u\, {\rm d}u\, {\rm d}v,\\&=\int_{1}^{2}-\frac{1}{2}\, {\rm d}v,\\&=-\frac{1}{2}.
\end{align*}

Just a small remark:

- First notice that we we are not integrating with density $1$ so there is no reason to expect a positive quantity for the double integral.
- I think that the selected transformations satisfy the injectivity of the change of variable, in addition to being of class  $C^1$, so everything seems to work fine out there.
- Of course a double integral can be negative, in this case notice that $u\in [-1,0]$.
- I can see that we do not agree with David G. Stork, please indicate me if my answer is incorrect and I will proceed to correct it and if it is hopelessly broken I will proceed to eliminate it.

Comment: OK, someone else with $\pm1/2$ makes me more confident. I have a sign error, which you can see because the domain is above $y=x$, i.e. in $y>x$, and hence $x^2-y^2<0$ so the answer must be $\le 0$.

Comment: Have removed my answer as yours is strictly better, +1

Comment: Thanks for the response. But can area be negative?

Comment: @YeshaParikh, $\int_D x^2 - y^2 dA$ is not the area of a region of the plane. It is the integral $\int_D f(x,y) dxdy$ of a function $f(x,y)=x^2-y^2$. Of course, the integral of a function can be negative, for example $\int_0^{1} -1 dx = -1 < 0$. The same here, but in 2D. My first comment above explains why the integral must be non-positive.

Answer (score 0):

No need to change variables:

[image]

$$\int\limits_{x=(\sqrt{5}-1)/2}^1 (x+1) - 1/x\ dx + \int\limits_{x=1}^\sqrt{2} 2/x - x\ dx = \frac{3}{4}-\frac{\sqrt{5}}{4}+\log \left(\sqrt{5}-1\right) = 0.402918$$

The first integral expresses the green area and the second the red area.

(This does not address the full $x^2 - y^2$ integrand question, which was not clear at the outset.)

Comment: Thank you for that! But the original question asks to approach it with change of variables. Is there any way with that?

Comment: Are you *SURE* it asks to change variables?  There is no principled or beneficial such approach.

Comment: Yep it asks to  use change of coordinates for approach

Comment: Please justify this more-than-terse response. Your software drew a beautiful picture, but how did the integrand $x^2-y^2$ disappear?

Comment: @TedShifrin:  My diagram was for the *original* posting of the problem, which made no mention of $x^2 - y^2$.  I haven't the time to go back to address the OP's revised question.

Comment: Looking at the edit history, the $x^2-y^2$ was there, albeit not in MathJax, from the outset. That said, I don’t see how your calculation gives just the area, either. If someone who’s taught multivariable for 50 years and written a textbook on it cannot follow your solution, it’s probably not appropriate for a learner.

Comment: @TedShifrin:  I confess I didn't see the $x^2 - y^2$.  Does my revision make the calculation clear?